# Scala MutableLists map-function return value

Tags: scala

At the moment I try to use the map function on a MutableList, because it would be more elegant then iterating with for-loops, imho.

When I do the following:

```
scala> ml
res2: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Double] = MutableList(1.0, 2.0)
```

So i have a MutableList like this and now I do:

```
scala> ml.map{ t:(Double) => t+0.2}
res3: scala.collection.mutable.LinearSeq[Double] = MutableList(1.2, 2.2)
```

I get a LinearSeq back. I want a MutableList back.
I assume map-functions on MutableLists arent the right way to do this? Or is there a easy way to go from a LinearSeq to a MutableList?

Comment: Why do you insist on wanting a `MutableList` back? The result is mutable just as well.

Comment: It's a class field I assign as a MutableList, has LinearSeq access in constant-time, too?

Comment: Actually, when I run your code, I get a `MutableList` after the map.. which Scala version is this you're using?

Comment: Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.final (OpenJDK Server VM, Java 1.6.0_24).

Comment: The actual version is 2.10. Just update your version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pagoda_5b mentioned, `mutable.LinearSeq` will allow the same operations as `MutableList`. In general, you should be instantiating the traits directly. For example, if you want a:

- Map to store (key -> value) pairs, call Map()
- Seq to store a list of things, call Seq()
- Set to store a set of things, call Set()
- Seq that has linear random access time, call IndexedSeq()
- etc..

Also good to note is that while both `MutableList` and `LinearSeq` have constant `head` access time, neither of the two have constant *random* access time, i.e. calling `linearSeq(n)` will take exactly n calls to `head` to return.

If you want mutable versions, simply add `import scala.collection.mutable` and use `mutable.Seq()`, for example. (Technically you could `import scala.collection.mutable.Seq`, however it is considered good coding style to prefix all mutable collections with the package name)

Answer (score 1):

As from [standard documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html#mutable_lists):

> Mutable Lists
>
> A [MutableList](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList.html) consists of a single linked list together with a pointer
>   that refers to the terminal empty node of that list. This makes list
>   append a constant time operation because it avoids having to traverse
>   the list in search for its terminal node. [MutableList](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList.html) is currently the
>   standard implementation of [mutable.LinearSeq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/collection/LinearSeq.html) in Scala.

Meaning that the returned `LinearSeq` is actually implemented as a `MutableList` => same access time